# How to convert nsstring to cString?

Tags: iphone, ios, c, string-conversion

I have a nsstring(filePath), which has the path to the audio file. I want open the audio file, so I want to convert the nsstring to Cstring.

```
  fopen([filePath cStringUsingEncoding:1], "r");
```

is the above line is correct or not, because I can also use `fopen([filePath cString], "r");`. In some websites it is mentioned to use UTF8stringEncoding. Which is the the right NSString to string conversion?

Comment: Pro-tip for English writing: punctuation marks should have a space after them, in order to separate sentences and phrases out from each other. This also allows a more natural form of line-wrapping, so that (for example, from your text) the string `not,because` is not treated by web clients as one word.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`UTF8String`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html):

```
fopen([filePath UTF8String], "r");
```

Comment: can i know the difference between your answer and what i used.how to checking whether it is working fine?

Comment: @Warrior, I think that reading the documentation will clear up any qualms you may have.

Comment: are you know how to convert audio file in Nsdata i use export session but is always failed

Comment: and a year later, you saved me time :)

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `UTF8String`, but `fileSystemRepresentation`.

You should do this because HFS+ or other file systems are not strictly compatible with the Unicode system. Another reason: This method operates by replacing the abstract path and extension separator characters (‘/’ and ‘.’ respectively) with their equivalents for the current file system.